# programming error in java due to static variable

Tags: java, variables, if-statement, for-loop, static

Following code is going in else statement. I am not able to find out where i made mistake.
*A want to execute in below comments.
*B is executing in below comments.

```
    package com.java;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Solution 
    {
       static int n;
       static String w[]; 

       public static void main(String[] args) 
       {
          System.out.println("enter no of string between 1 to 50");
          Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
//* A
          if ((1<n) && (n<=50))
          {
             n = scanner.nextInt();
             System.out.println("enter " +n+  "strings between 1 to 2000 length");              
             for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
             {
                 w[i]= scanner.next();
                 if ((1<w[i].length()) && (w[i].length()<2000))
                 {
                    System.out.println("ok");           
                 }
             }
             System.out.println(w); 
          }
// *B 
         else
          {
             System.out.println("coming due to static");
          }    
       }
    }
```

Comment: properly indenting your code would do wonders for figuring out what you mean by 'case 1' and 'case 2'.

Comment: With what you've written, n will always be 0, because it is a static and you are never changing its value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't initialize `n`, so you're not satisfying the `if` condition, since uninitialized `static int` variables are `0` by default.

So:

`if ((1<n) && (n<=50))` is not evaluated to `true`, so `else` will be executed.

Note that you **can't** access *static variable* from *non-static method* (See @NilsH answer). And that's make a lot of sense..

Comment: One of the most things I hate here.. is anonymous downvoters that doesn't explain their downvotes.. How should we learn from mistakes this way?

Comment: You missed the fact he missed the call to n = scanner.nextInt(); before the if-statement, rest is correct.

Comment: I don't read minds. I wrote why his code doesn't work, there is a million ways for fix this.

Comment: It's very obvious, no mind reading necessary.. look at the code I reformatted for him

Comment: "*there is another problem with your code in reading the next number you want to read, but I will leave that for you to solve.*" - This was part of your answer, applying this to your comment here, you missed many facts ;)

Answer (score 4):

`static` means that it is a class variable, that is, it does not belong to an instance of the class. And opposite, a non static variable belongs to an instance of the class. You're referencing the variable `n` from a static method, and hence, it will not work unless the variable also is declared static.

(and obviously, the `if` itself won't work because of what the reply from @MarounMaroun mention)

Answer (score 1):

First, when working with `static` methods, you must reference `static` variables. If you try to reference a `non-static` variable that belongs to a class, the compiler will complain because that is wrong. Static variables do not belong to a class per se.

Second, I think you have a typo or forgot some code. `n` is never set - ever. Therefore, since in the `static` context it will be zero initialized and hit the else. I think you meant for `n` to actually be set before the `if` statement either via user-input or some other means. If you leave everything `static` and actually provide a value for `n`, then your code should work.

For instance, you probably need to make this assignment:

`n = scanner.nextInt();`

before the if-statement.

there is another problem with your code in reading the next number you want to read, but I will leave that for you to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making `static int n` and `static String w[]` public?

IE:

```
public static int n ;
public static String w[] ;
```

Answer (score 0):

what you probably want is moving all that code to a non-static method. and then in your main method just do something like this

```
Solution s = new Solution();
s.myNonStaticMethod();
```